# Z3 4.0 Extra Output in Model

Tags: z3

When I am trying to get a model string, along with the variables that I define, I get extra output in the model as -

```
 z3name!0=3, z3name!1=-2, z3name!10=0, z3name!11=0, z3name!12=0, z3name!13=0, z3name!14=0, z3name!15=0, z3name!2=0, z3name!3=0, z3name!4=2, z3name!5=2, z3name!6=0, z3name!7=-3, z3name!8=2, z3name!9=0
```

I want to know that is this erroneous output?
Or is it some intermediate variables that are being used by Z3?

Because the values for the variables I have defined seems okay to me.
I have not seen previously any such output, thus I got this doubt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Z3 has several preprocessing steps. Some of them introduce new variables. The new variables are usually removed from the resulting model. If they are not, this is a bug. However, this bug does *not* affect correctness. It is just an inconvenience.

It would be great if you could post your problem. We would be able to identify which preprocessing step is not eliminating the introduced auxiliary variables.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old topic, but I found myself having the same "bug" as Leonardo called it. Since the OP did not post his code, I thought mine could maybe help fix it (even though this extra output is not a problem for me as long as correctness is indeed preserved).

It appears that if I change the "/" in the final assertion for, let's say, a "+" operator, the problem disappears.

```
(declare-fun fun0!0 () Int)
(declare-fun fun0!-1 () Int)
(declare-fun var0 () Int)

(assert (and
    (and
        (or (= fun0!0 0) (= fun0!0 1) (= fun0!0 2))
        (or (= fun0!-1 0) (= fun0!-1 1) (= fun0!-1 2))
        (or (= var0 1) (= var0 -1))
    )
    (and (or (= var0 0) (= var0 -1)))
))

(define-fun fun0 ((i! Int)) Int
    (ite
        (= i! 0)
        fun0!0
        (ite
            (= i! -1)
            fun0!-1
            (- 0 1)
        )
    )
)

(assert (=
    (fun0 var0)
    (/ var0 var0)
))
(check-sat)
```